# Creating a Sliding Pane Activity with Two Subordinate Panes

Tags: android

There's an Android app called [Sliding Messaging](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klinker.android.messaging_donate&hl=en) (Google Play Link), which is just a simple text messaging application. In the app, you can swipe from the left margin to open up a list of open conversations, or you can swipe from the right margin to open up a pane to start a new conversation.

I know that Google recently added the [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) to their support library, however that library only seems to support swiping from the left, not the right.

Are there any 3rd party libraries out there that offer this sort of functionality? Or does Android's own Sliding Pane allow for swiping from the left or right margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of this library [`slidingMenu`](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) which you can configure your reveal mechanism, `left-right` of `right-left`

Comment: Oh sweet! How I didn't run into that already, I have no idea. This looks perfect! Thanks!